# Image link not working for GridView ButtonField

Tags: c#, gridview

I am trying to create a column in a GridView that contains a button and can be clicked on to select the row. When I try to assign an ImageURL (that exists) to the button, it does not display and seems as if the link is broken. Here's the code I am using:

```
<asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Select" ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Select" ImageUrl="../Images/SemiWorksPLM/unchecked.png"/>
```

However I can create an Image inside a TemplateField using the same URL and it appears okay:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="../Images/SemiWorksPLM/unchecked.png" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any idea why it would work for the Image in the TemplateField but not the ButtonField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try doing it the next way:

1 - Change ButtonType to to link 
2 - put the image in the text area

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Preview" Text="<img src='Images/SemiWorksPLM/unchecked.png' style='border-width:0' />" ButtonType="Link" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a url relative the the root directory of the website:

```
 ImageUrl="~/Images/Image2.bmp"
```